# Odd Dependency Error While Using Jekyll Serve

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm getting a weird error while trying to jekyll serve.

```
Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jemoji or one of 
its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, 
you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'Unable 
to activate activesupport-4.2.7.1, because json-2.0.3 conflicts with 
json (>= 1.7.7, ~> 1.7)' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources 
at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled but can't figure the problem out. I've done a gem update and the actual versions I have are below:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (5.0.1, 4.2.7.1)

...

jemoji (0.8.0)

json (2.0.3, default: 2.0.2, 1.8.6)

...
```

Comment: Looks like Activesupport is using an newer Json version than another dependency, like Jemoji. Can you check what dependency uses what version of Json?

Comment: jemoji is using activesupport 4.2~ which is dependent on json 1.7.7~ but that's not installed.

Comment: And what is using json 2.0? Looks like json 1.x and 2.x are conflicting

Comment: The problem is jemoji has a dependency on activesupport 4.0 which has the dependency on json 1.7.  In activesupport 5.0, the json dependency is removed.  However, jemoji hasn't updated the specfile.  If I knew how to modify the dependency locally, I'll get rid of the line.  

https://github.com/jekyll/jemoji/blob/master/jemoji.gemspec

Comment: When I go to fetch the gem version, I get several 67 errors during the build.  

    ERROR:  Error installing json:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/getChester/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2158:12: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
        ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    67 warnings and 3 errors generated.
    make: *** [generator.o] Error 1